# render Image not outputting Shiny

Tags: shiny

```
  output$plot <- renderImage({
  
outfile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
png(outfile, width = 400, height = 300)
venn.diagram(
  x = list(
    T = T,
    I = I
  ),
  main = "Venn Diagram ",
  filename =outfile, output=TRUE,
  lwd = 2,na = "remove",
  fill = c("orange", "blue"),
  alpha = c(0.5,0.5),
  label.col = "black",
  cex=1.5,
  fontface = "plain",
  cat.col = c("cornflowerblue", "pink"),
  cat.cex = 1.5,
  cat.fontfamily = "serif",
  cat.fontface = "plain",
  cat.dist = c(0.05, 0.05),
  cat.pos = c(-20, 14),
  cat.default.pos = "text",
  scaled = FALSE
)
dev.off()

list(src = outfile,
     contentType = 'image/png',
     width = 400,
     height = 300,
     alt = "This is alternate text")
}, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

I was trying plot a venn diagram using this code. But it only displays This is alternate text and not outputting any image on the app, Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a reactive graph as shown below

```
output$plot <- renderImage({
    vennd <- reactive({venn.diagram(
      x = list(
        T = T,
        I = I
      ),
      main = "Venn Diagram ",
      filename =outfile, output=TRUE,
      lwd = 2,na = "remove",
      fill = c("orange", "blue"),
      alpha = c(0.5,0.5),
      label.col = "black",
      cex=1.5,
      fontface = "plain",
      cat.col = c("cornflowerblue", "pink"),
      cat.cex = 1.5,
      cat.fontfamily = "serif",
      cat.fontface = "plain",
      cat.dist = c(0.05, 0.05),
      cat.pos = c(-20, 14),
      cat.default.pos = "text",
      scaled = FALSE
    )
    })
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
    png(outfile, width = 400, height = 300)
    vennd()
    dev.off()
    
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 400,
         height = 300,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

Comment: Still no out put

Comment: I get the output with `shinydashboard::box(imageOutput("plot", height = "550px")` on the `ui` side. Obviously, I am plotting another plot.

Comment: I think its about venn.diagram package

Comment: First you need to verify that you can get a plot in RStudio, without using Shiny.

Answer (score 0):

```
output$plot <- renderImage({
 
  vennd <- reactive({venn.diagram(
    x = list(
       T = T,
       I = I
    ),
    main = "",
    filename =outfile, output=TRUE,
    lwd = 2,na = "remove",imagetype="png",
    fill = c("orange", "blue"),
    alpha = c(0.5,0.5),
    label.col = "black",
    cex=1.5,
    fontface = "plain",
    cat.col = c("cornflowerblue", "pink"),
    cat.cex = 1.5,
    cat.fontfamily = "serif",
    cat.fontface = "plain",
    cat.dist = c(0.05, 0.05),
    cat.pos = c(-20, 14),
    cat.default.pos = "text",
    scaled = FALSE
  )
  })
  outfile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  png(outfile, width = 500, height = 500,type="cairo")
  vennd()
   dev.off()
  
  list(src = outfile,
       contentType = 'image/png',
       width = 500,
       height = 500,
       alt = "This is alternate text")
}, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

Need to add imagetype="png" and type="cairo" thank you @YBS